# Set Stroke Colour by

Tags: ios, rgb, uicolor, picker, stroke

I'm creating a drawing app and I would like to integrate [NKO-Colour-Picker](https://github.com/FWCarlos/NKO-Color-Picker-View-iOS) but the problem is I would like to use the `UIColor` from the picker as the stroke colour when a user draws on my `UIView`.

How would I do this as `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor` is coded in RGB values not `UIColor`?

I currently have this:

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
UIColor *color = ... // your selected color
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), color.CGColor);
```

or simply do:

```
[color set];
```

or:

```
[color setStroke];
```

Comment: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), color.CGColor); - worked perfectly, thank you so much!